# `dplyr` distribution draw by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a random variable `measured` with a normal distribution but a mean based on another variable in my `data.frame`. For syntax and efficiency reasons I want to do this in `dplyr`, which I am new to.

```
library(dplyr)
fake <- data.frame(group = rbinom(50,1,0.5))
fake %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(measured = rnorm(1, group, 0.5))

Source: local data frame [50 x 2]
Groups: group

   group      measured
1      1  0.3501516392
2      0 -0.0004234461
3      1  0.3501516392
4      0 -0.0004234461
5      0 -0.0004234461
6      0 -0.0004234461
7      1  0.3501516392
8      0 -0.0004234461
9      1  0.3501516392
10     1  0.3501516392
```

The problem here is that I get a single draw appended to each group rather than an independent draw at each observation.

How can I call `rnorm` to the length of my groups? Or is there a different function I should use for the random draw?

### Update:

So I figured out that I can call the length of the group, `length(group)`. This gives the desired behavior, but I can't tell if I'm calling for `nrow(fake)` draws or `brow(fake[group == 1,])` draws. Any further advice?

```
fake <- data.frame(group= rbinom(200,1,0.5))
fake <- fake %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(random = rnorm(length(group), group, 0.5))
ggplot(fake, aes(x = random, fill = factor(group))) + geom_density(alpha=0.4)
```

[image: Distribution of draws by group]

Comment: Incidentally, upgrade your `dplyr` version, `%.%` has been replaced by `%>%`.

Comment: I installed it this morning. But I can update my syntax, I suppose.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware to that the old syntax was still supported. Okay then.

Comment: `dplyr` also has `n()` so you don't need to use `length(group)`

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to point out that grouping is not even necessary. `rnorm` can take a vector of means, so you can just pass it the entire `group` column without telling it to treat groups separately:

```
fake %>%
  mutate(measured = rnorm(nrow(fake),group,0.5)) %>%
  head

  group    measured
1     1  1.16004276
2     0 -0.05366081
3     0 -0.78353925
4     0  0.01429192
5     0  0.26340507
6     0 -0.34022501
```

Or equivalently, as pointed out by @rrs :

```
fake %>%
  mutate(measured = rnorm(n(),group,0.5))
```